# Is it safe to use the tip of a hot glue gun to melt crayons?

Tags: safety, oil-pastels

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FV4hfmODq94) (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FV4hfmODq94) mentions the following methods to melt crayons:

1. Putting the crayons into the hot glue gun.
2. Using a hair dryer and point to the crayons.
3. Using a lighted candle and point to the crayons.

So, I was wondering if the following method can be a fourth method to melt crayons?

- By using the tip of a hot glue gun to slowly melt a crayon.

Will that cause any damages to the hot glue gun?
And are there any precautions that I need to take note of?

Answer (score 4):

It will work, as high temperatures melt the crayons, regardless of the device you use, but in all cases I'd suggest **doing it in a well-ventilated room or outside**, as the fumes are a little toxic.

Also note that holding the crayon in one hand while doing so is asking for trouble: **wear a glove, or attach the crayon sturdily to something**.

I'm sure **crayons won't damage the glue gun** more extremely than the glues it is used for (I mean, the tip of the hot glue gun is made to withstand damage).